# Remove Checkbox in a Yes/No Field in MS Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2007

When I create a field whose type is Yes/No in the Design View, it appears as a checkbox. IS there a way for it to appear as words like True or False or Yes or No? I am using MS Access 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Lookup tab and select Display Control as TextBox

[image]

Now the table field `Yes/No`  will appear as `True` or `False`. You can set the default value from General Tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the design view for the table, select the column and then the lookup tab at the bottom. Change the display control to text box or combo box.